# What happens to CPU mode if CPU time slice expires during CPU mode switch?

Tags: multithreading, kernel, context-switch

Recently, I'm studying about CPU cores, threads, scheduling and and their relations. Apart from definitions of [CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit), [thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)), scheduling, [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch), [protection ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring), [CPU mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes), and thread context, [this article](https://flylib.com/books/en/3.169.1.53/1/) was very helpful in understanding what is going on under the hood, in case of windows.

I thought CPU mode switch was included in thread context so that CPU sets its mode to either kernel or user mode **whenever thread context switch occurs** and CPU executes a thread, precisely a thread's code or instructions.

However, from [Context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch)

> "When the system transitions between user mode and kernel mode, a context switch is not necessary; a mode transition is not by itself a context switch. However, depending on the operating system, a context switch may also take place at this time."

**Does this mean thread context switch does not include CPU mode transition?**

**What happens to CPU mode if CPU time slice expires during CPU mode switch?**

For example, a thread began execution in user mode and switches to kernel mode, due to such as system call. The thread time slice expires. CPU mode left as kernel mode. Doesn't this lead to CPU executing next thread in kernel mode?

Comment: Not going to "answer" because I don't know enough details of any actual OS, but I would expect that the CPU is _always_ in "kernel" mode during a contex switch. If the switch occurred because the thread was preempted while running in "user" mode, then it will happen within a timer interrupt, and the interrupt will have put the CPU into kernel mode. The only other possibility is if the context switch occurs during a system call, in which case, the CPU once again will be running in kernel mode.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Solomon Slow. I'm sorry about not mentioning OS. OS is Windows.